# The extra function written for the DeleteView class does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have added a function that if the post is deleted by the user, it will be deleted if there is an uploaded photo, but the function does not work.

my view:

```
class NewsDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/news_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('news_list')

    def delete_header_image(self, pk):
        news = get_object_or_404(News, id = pk)
        header_image = news.header_image
        if header_image is not None:
            os.remove(str(header_image))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news_list'))
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news_list'))

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.has_perm('news.all') or self.request.user.has_perm('news.delete_news') or obj.author == self.request.user:
            return True
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:pk>/delete', NewsDeleteView.as_view(), name='news_delete'),
]
```

models:

```
def get_header_image_filepath(self, filepath):
    return f'images/news/header/{self.author.id}/{self.header_image}'


class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    header_image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=get_header_image_filepath)
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("news_detail", args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Are you talking about that `delete_header_image`? Why do you think it will be called?

Comment: Also it is not clear whether you just want to remove the image or want to delete the `News` instance, please clarify.

Comment: I want to delete the instance, but when it is deleted, the uploaded image will not be deleted, so I wrote this function(delete_header_image), but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class based views do not work magically. They have some methods already written which are called to perform actions. Hence you writing a method `delete_header_image` does not mean it will be called automatically. Instead you should override some suitable method of the class which will be called internally. For `DeleteView` the method that performs the deletion is `delete` and hence you should override that. Also the condition `if header_image is not None` will not work since even if there is no file it will not be represented by `None` instead you should simply write `if header_image` for checking. Furthermore instead of deleting manually simply call [`ieldFile.delete` [Django Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.delete):

```py
class NewsDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = News
    template_name = 'news/news_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('news_list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        object = self.get_object()
        if object.header_image:
            object.header_image.delete(save=False)
        return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user.has_perm('news.all') or self.request.user.has_perm('news.delete_news') or obj.author == self.request.user:
            return True
```

Comment: The code you wrote solved my problem. Thank you very much.